# How to return an entire array (NO FILTER!!!!!), from mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

heres my mongodb group document. As you can see i have an _id, which i use to find the group itself, an owner, an array of admins and an array of members.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c7246f61a6cc7527f815d2"
    },
    "groupName": "soogroo1",
    "creationDate": "11/06/2020",
    "premiumStatus": true,
    "phone": "08741536329995757575757575757575577575757575",
    "profilePic": "post-5f2a01e2-efe3-4fa0-8302-76bfd2d70b4b-1622806860268",
    "owner": ["9b8bcd57-06eb-471c-8910-c5b944d02431"],
    "admin": ["f2171431-627e-47a3-a65f-4abf48d361b6", "5e3df015-a1ed-4a63-a16e-83458d0e7da3", "f85baa4a-1015-4a5e-b1ed-b79001a9f277"],
    "member": ["6b1233b2-098e-480b-9462-c010c8b8de06", "0bcbb92d-6276-4118-8576-9d5f5c4ed43b"]
}
```

essentially i have searched the entirety of the world wide web looking for one of possibly the simplest most fundamental thing i can think of, how on gods green earth do you query an array of strings, and return the entire array. All i want to do is pass in a group id, specify that i want the entire member field returned, and then ill be able to map the members to a list on the front-end like you would with following/followers on instagram for example.

Everywhere i look all i can find is people who use arrays of objects and people who filter arrays and all that bs, i just want the entire array string for string returned. Please help i'm pulling my hair out lol.

BTW im using nodeJS with express and reactJS on the front-end (not that that's relevant)

```
vvvvv RELEVANT CODE vvvvv
```

folder name : routes

file name : groups.js

```
app.get("/groups/:groupId/members", (req, res)=>{
    groups.getGroupsMembers(req.params.groupId).then(data=>{
        res.send(data) 
    })
})
```

folder name : main

file name : groups.js

```
   exports.getGroupsMembers = (groupId) => {
    return myMongo.getGroupsMemberList("groups", groupId);

};
```

folder name : main

file name : mongo.js

vvvvvv (the part that is broken) vvvvvv

```
exports.getGroupsMemberList = (collection, groupId) => {
  return db.collection(collection).findOne(
    { _id: ObjectID(groupId)},
  ).members
}
```

Comment: why not just `(await db.groups.find( { _id: "foo" } ) ).members`?

Comment: @user3133 , thanks for your comment man. no luck sadly.

Comment: Let me get this right, so you want to query a mongodb groups, that has documents with attributes as specified in your question. From that query, you want to get members array?  
1. get group with id 'foo'  
2. get attribute members from group foo

Comment: @user3133 , where do you see 'foo' , the id is {_id : "60c7246f61a6cc7527f815d2"}.  I have a mongoDB profile with multiple collections, users, groups and many more. in this case users and groups are all thats relevant. within groups i have a group called "soogroo1" as seen in the groupName field. i want to search for that group by id. and once i have the group, return the entire members array.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have no way to test your code, but I guess your problem is because you are extending query with .members, not actually getting members attribute from the return value of query.

```
exports.getGroupsMemberList = async (collection, groupId) => {
  return await (db.collection(collection).findOne(
    { _id: ObjectID(groupId)},
  )).members
}
```

I am not sure if mongo driver accepts async/await, so you might need to do this through callbacks..?

Comment: `exports.getGroupsOwnerList = async (collection, groupId) => {     return` `(db.collection(collection).findOne(       { _id: ObjectID(groupId)},       {projection:` `{owner: 1}}       ))}` probably looks stupid answering my own question but i solved my problem using projection ass seen above

Comment: defo not! If you found a solution, it's more than okay to post it here. There might be others struggling with similar problem and your solution might just be what they are looking for ;)